# GridGain join query for two objects

Tags: java, caching, join, gridgain

I am using GridGain as local in-memory storage of my data objects (pojos) and I need to query those objects and select the proper one with specific values. Lets consider the following situation:

```
class Person {

    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public Organization organization;
}

class Organization{

  public Long id;
  public String name;
}
```

Could you advice how to make query to retrieve e.g. all Persons for certain Organization? 
I tried following:

```
final GridCacheProjection<GridCacheAffinityKey<Long>, Person> appCache = cache.projection(GridCacheAffinityKey.class, Person.class);

final GridCacheQuery<Map.Entry<GridCacheAffinityKey<Long>, Person>> query = appCache.queries().createSqlQuery(Person.class, "from Person, Organization " + "where Person.organization.id = " + "Organization.id = ?");
```

But no luck. I found a lot of examples using Person.id = Organization.id = ? however I have Organization as an object in Person class so how to write a query or retrieve data in this way?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look right.

Take a look at [CacheQueryExample](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/CacheQueryExample.java) available on GitHub (also shipped with GridGain)

Specifically at the part that does the join:

```
// Create query which joins on 2 types to select people for a specific organization.
GridCacheQuery<Map.Entry<GridCacheAffinityKey<UUID>, Person>> qry = cache.queries().
    createSqlQuery(Person.class,
        "from Person, Organization " + "where Person.orgId = Organization.id and " +
        "lower(Organization.name) = lower(?)");

// Execute queries for find employees for different organizations.
print("Following people are 'GridGain' employees: ", qry.execute("GridGain").get());
print("Following people are 'Other' employees: ", qry.execute("Other").get());
```

Comment: Hello Dmitriy, thanks for response. I saw this example and create my code based on it. However scenario described by GridGain documentation expect that your objects (Person, Organization) are exact representation of DB schema => reference between them is done by "foreign key"/UUID which is a single value. However in my data model my Person class has as a reference whole Organization object. Therefore I have not the possibility to search simply by comparing Person.id with Organisation.id with some single value. Isn't there a way how to do this? Perhaps by implementing some compare/equal method?